# Jquery splash not fading in — but is fading out

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, splash-screen, fadeout

I'm currently trying to get this splash page to fade in, then fade out. However, it is just fading out, not fading in.

Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.all').hide(); 
$('#surprisesplash').fadeIn(1500)
});
$(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
     $('#surprisesplash').fadeOut(1000, function() {
     $('.all').fadeIn();
  });
 }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

and here is the [website.](http://camelotmusic.co.uk)

I'm quite new at this, and still getting to grips. Any help on syntax or any of the like would also be appreciated.

Tom :)

This is the css

```
#surprisesplash {

    width:850px;
    height:621px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-310.5px;
    margin-left:-425px;
    position:fixed;

    }

.all {
    display:none;

    }
```

html:

```
  <div id="surprisesplash"><img src="/surprise2.png"></div>

    <div class ="all">

    <div id = "header">
        <div id = "music">Camelot</div>         
        <div id = "about"><a href="#">About</a></div>
        <div id = "contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id = "musicinfo">

        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
        Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
        Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. 
        Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. 
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></div>

        <div id = "aboutinfo">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
        Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
        Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. </p></div>

            <div id = "contactinfo">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
        Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget. </p></div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably at least wait until it's finished fading in before you start fading out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.all').hide(); 
        $('#suprisesplash').fadeIn(1500, function() {
            $(this).delay(1500).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $('.all').fadeIn();                     
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. I pasted that code in, and seemed to freeze the splash — not fading out or fading in! :s

Comment: You need to start with an element that is hidden, so set `#front` to `display: none` in the CSS, and since `.all` is already hidden you don't have to hide it with jQuery. Look at this [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3wGsg/), I made the splash screen red as I did'nt bother linking in the images etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, that got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

It should work!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.all').hide();
    $('#surprisesplash').fadeIn(1500);

    setTimeout(function() {

        $('#surprisesplash').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $('.all').fadeIn(1500);    
        });

    }, 3000);

    </script>
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/TaCKy/)**

Comment: Nope, the css is this: `#surprisesplash {
 
 width:850px;
 height:621px;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 margin-top:-310.5px;
 margin-left:-425px;
 position:fixed;
 background-color:none; 
 display:hidden;
 }`